# How to write into a file in c++ and php reading from that file anytime there is a value?

Tags: php, c++

I have created a c++ code and once the program start it is suppose to create a file. My problem is: I have a variable that holds a value which constantly change. I want to write to this file created by c++ and allow php to read from this file any time a new value appears in the file.

The variable g=50. How to write to a file in c++?

Comment: well whats the problem? please add your code and tell us what is not working :)

Comment: Please try to improve your spelling. Although high level English is not expected here, but you can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want nothing more than this value in the output file, you can just create your ofstream with the out and trunc bits set, write the value, then close the stream.  Every time you want to change the value, do all of these steps again.

```
std::ofstream ofs("file.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc):
ofs << g:
ofs.close();
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode